# Checking product purchase status

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I wondering what a best way to check in-app-purchase product status on app launching. Do I need to save purchase status on device or ask for status app store on every app launching?

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 7 is recommended to use the App Store receipt to save the status of IAP.

You can find out more in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW16). But in most cases is `NSUserDefaults` enough. E.g. I use [IAPManager](https://github.com/mruegenberg/IAPManager) to handle all for me which persists all on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You should save in-app-purchase status on your device, using `NSUserDefaults`for example.

Imagine someone bought some in-app purchases from your app, and want to use it somewhere where the network is slow or doesn't work at all : if you doesn't store the information locally, then the user will be unable to use the unlocked features of your app.

This [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started) concerning in-app purchases 
provides an useful class, `IAPHelper`, which helps you manage your products easily, you should check it.